# Como passar uma tag HTML dentro de um JavaScript

Tags: latex

Estou tentando realizar uma atividade matemática no Moodle utilizando o Ardora como criador das atividades. Ele faz a parte do javascript, css e html por mim, então as atividades de idiomas sao "simples". Meu problema estão nas atividades com matemática, pois preciso passar fórmulas através dos parâmetros e fazer as devidas comparações (pergunta e resposta) para ver se o aluno acertou ou não.

Eu tenho os arquivos, já localizei onde tenho que alterar, mas não estou conseguindo (ou sabendo) o que e como alterar.

Vou dar um exemplo de como deve ser a atividade

Perguntas:          Respostas:
Cachorro            Kitty
Gato                Chovinista
Porco               Max

De um lado, tenho a coluna com as perguntas e do outro, as repostas, nas quais os alunos devem arrastar para os devidos campos e fazer as associações. Por exemplo, Max deve ir com Cachorro, Kitty com Gato e Chovinista com Porco.

Tenho que fazer a mesma coisa, mas puxando fórmulas matemáticas, exemplo:

1 + 2 =                   5
1 / 2 =                  0,5
5 * 1 =                   3

Nesse tipo de exemplo, como nao usei fórmulas, fica fácil fazer. Agora quando tenho que usar as expressões matemáticas, tenho que conseguir colocar isso na tela no formato das fórmulas (tentei jogar um js que formata o tex em html), e nada.

Queria fazer algo assim:

```
ax^2 + bx + c = 0
srqt(8)
\frac(8)\(1)
```

Podem me ajudar? Se precisarem de mais detalhes eu passo. Se não ficou claro a explicação ou o problema, tento melhorar a escrita.

Comment: Olá Eriberto, seja bem vindo ao SOPT. Eu editei o texto e o título levemente, retirando as saudações e os agradecimentos, e coloquei a expressão dividida em linhas, na formatação de código, porque acho que explica melhor o que quer fazer... Você pode reverter a edição ou editar por cima algo de algo que não concordar na edição. Sobre a pergunta,  não entendi muito bem o que quer fazer, mas pra escrever o código acho que seria possível fazer com as tags `pre`e `code`... mas não tenho certeza... dá uma olhada: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp e http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_code.asp

Comment: Obrigado. Sou usuário de fóruns em geral, mas desse eu sou novo. :)

Comment: Legal. O SOPT não é exatamente um fórum, mas é bem útil... se ainda não viu, depois dá uma olhada no [tour]... Abraços.

Comment: Oi. Só vi a pergunta hoje (desculpe). Mas eu ainda não entendi a sua dificuldade/necessidade. O que exatamente vc precisa fazer? O que quer dizer "conseguir colocar isso na tela"? Tá bem confuso, e eu não vi a relevância do LaTeX nessa questão.